# Any other procedure for Divorce for women other than Khula?

Tags: talaq

Someone asked me and i don't know the answer so please anyone have the answer then reply me that is, in islam, is there is any way for women to take divorce other than khula and her husband is so cruel he always use to beat her, sell her jewellery, take her money and consume Alcohol when she asked for divorce then he denied to give her divorce and she don't want to move to court for certain reasons. Being a law student i said that don't worry i will help you in the court but i don't know why she is not ready. So please if you have any solution then tell me. With this We can save a life

Comment: Khula is the only method a female can separate.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK in islam divorce (talaq) can normally only come from the husband.

[Khula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khula) is a way for a wife to "buy herself free" if her husband doesn't want to divorce her, but she asked him for. This would at least mean that she gives him his mahr back to get ride of him.

Then there is a 3rd possibility called [Faskh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulment#Annulment_in_Islam) فسخ which is a kind of an anullment of the marriage and will need a court to separate them! But it seems the conditions for it are not fulfilled in this case!

As you can read [here](http://www.islam21c.com/fataawa/912-fatwa-a-civil-divorce-is-not-a-valid-islamic-divorce/)

And Allah knows best!